# I want to adjust my paragraph on small screens with google adsense banner

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to adjust my content with google banner for small screens.
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYDSO.png)

there is parent div with class name `parent-content` and banner div named `ad3`.

Here is my code for screen max-600px

```
    .parent-content
{
    position: relative;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -moz-hyphens:auto;
    -ms-hyphens:auto;
    -webkit-hyphens:auto;
    hyphens:auto;
  }
  .ad3
{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
  }
```

Result:
[My Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ai5.png)

Looking forward to hear solutions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put you HTML code in a snippet with the CSS

Comment: I got solution. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

you can put ad code inside `<div>` and do `float:right;` so text wraps around it

Something like this:

```
<div style="float:right;">
     ADSENSE CODE HERE
</div>
```

Maybe add margins, so text is separated from ad

I would avoid using

```
position: absolute;
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

because google may thing you trying to do something like a **sticky ad**, which is against TOS